# MySQL 5.6.39 - Are these statements appropriate for a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am attempting to streamline some tasks and Instead of a bash script which spawns a few mysqlclient processes I believe that stored procedures would actually be a faster method

I have tried some python scripts and some other bash scripts and they work ok, but I am curious if a stored procedure with a few event triggers is better

Note: This would be applied to ~700 schema-identical dbs and either run simultaneously or sequentially through scripting (some advice there would be nice as well.  If it would be better suited in trying some sort of multithreading with python id like to know

````
    USE `<db>`;
    DROP procedure IF EXISTS `archive_table`;

    DELIMITER //
    USE `basegps3`//
    CREATE PROCEDURE `archive_table`(IN trunc_date DATETIME)
    BEGIN

        DECLARE max_loc_id INT DEFAULT 1;

        SELECT IFNULL(MAX(location_id),1) INTO max_loc_id FROM location;
        INSERT IGNORE INTO arc_location SELECT * FROM location WHERE update_time < trunc_date AND location_id != max_loc_id;
        DELETE FROM location WHERE update_time < trunc_date AND location_id != max_loc_id;
        INSERT IGNORE INTO location SELECT l.* FROM arc_location l INNER JOIN vehicle_info USING(location_id);
        DELETE FROM arc_location WHERE location_id IN (SELECT location_id FROM vehicle_info);
        INSERT IGNORE INTO arc_message SELECT * FROM message WHERE create_time < trunc_date;
        DELETE FROM message WHERE create_time < trunc_date;
        INSERT IGNORE INTO arc_qt_answer SELECT * FROM qt_answer WHERE date_time < trunc_date;
        INSERT IGNORE INTO arc_phone_error SELECT * FROM phone_error WHERE timestamp < trunc_date;
        DELETE FROM phone_error WHERE timestamp < trunc_date;
        INSERT IGNORE INTO arc_status_change SELECT * FROM status_change WHERE timestamp < trunc_date AND most_recent = 0;
        DELETE FROM status_change WHERE timestamp < trunc_date and most_recent = 0;
        INSERT IGNORE INTO arc_area_points SELECT * FROM area_points WHERE area_id IN (SELECT area_id FROM area WHERE expire_time IS NOT NULL AND expire_time < trunc_date AND area_type_id = 1);
        DELETE FROM area_points WHERE area_id IN (SELECT area_id FROM area WHERE expire_time IS NOT NULL AND expire_time < trunc_date AND area_type_id = 1);
        INSERT IGNORE INTO arc_hotspot SELECT * FROM hotspot WHERE area_id IN (SELECT area_id FROM area WHERE expire_time IS NOT NULL AND expire_time < trunc_date AND area_type_id = 1);
        DELETE FROM hotspot WHERE area_id IN (SELECT area_id FROM area WHERE expire_time IS NOT NULL AND expire_time < trunc_date AND area_type_id = 1);
        INSERT IGNORE INTO arc_area SELECT * FROM area WHERE expire_time IS NOT NULL AND expire_time < trunc_date AND area_type_id = 1;
        DELETE FROM area WHERE expire_time IS NOT NULL AND expire_time < trunc_date AND area_type_id = 1;
        INSERT IGNORE INTO arc_area_time SELECT * FROM area_time WHERE exit_timestamp IS NOT NULL AND exit_timestamp < trunc_date;
        DELETE FROM area_time WHERE exit_timestamp IS NOT NULL AND exit_timestamp < trunc_date;
        INSERT IGNORE INTO arc_ed_sample_data SELECT * FROM ed_sample_data WHERE timestamp < trunc_date;
        DELETE FROM ed_sample_data WHERE timestamp < trunc_date;
    END//

    DELIMITER ;```
````

Comment: Using 5.6.3 in a production isn't appropriate, its a effectively an alpha release. [Take care when upgrading](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-3.html) (top note). Backup before any update.

Comment: Stored procedures have no inherent speed improvement attribute. They are hard to debug also. If your existing scripts work ok I wouldn't' change them.

Comment: @danblack sorry, its 5.6.39 in Amazon RDS specifically

Comment: You seem to be archiving data, how are you using this? Are you doing this because you have a performance problem with this data in the current table? If so ask about improving that performance.

Comment: correct, just moving data to another table